# What's the difference between posting from a html-form and using the webclient class?

Tags: .net, silverlight, webclient, http-post

When I Inspect with firebug I notice that when posting with a regular html form it sets the contenttype to application/x-www-form-urlencoded, but when using the Webclient class it doesn't. And when i use the webclient class from an silverlight app I must fetch the data from
the inputstream and make the corresponding conversion.

How can you add items to the Request.Form property with a webclient class? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

[Silverlight HTTP POST few variables, SIMPLEST example (least code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493921/silverlight-http-post-few-variables-simplest-example-least-code/3496681#3496681)