# Silverlight + webrequest HTTP POST large data

Tags: silverlight, post, webrequest

I am making a webrequest call from Silverlight to a service that supports basic authentication and accepts two input string parameters. The request works correctly and gets back results when the POST data is small. However, when one of the string parameters was more than 2MB, the request was not sent correctly. When I investigated in Fiddler, the parameter with huge data is just empty. Is there a limitation on sending POST data? or is there any setting that I am missing?

My code is similar to the one found on the first post of this link 
[Silverlight HTTP POST few variables, SIMPLEST example (least code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493921/silverlight-http-post-few-variables-simplest-example-least-code)

Any input is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This limitation can have been set on the web server you are requesting. If you have control of the service, you should look at the web.config file. You should edit or add <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="[size in KB]" />